# Simplifying logging in Flask

Tags: python, logging, flask

I currently have this as my basic logger for my Flask application. Although I see that there is an [Flask.logger object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.logger). How do I make use of the native Flask logger? Or is what I'm doing below just fine?

I'm also a little confused as to where the different logging statuses go, for example logging to info versus logging to error?

```
LOG_FILENAME = 'app_access_logs.log'

info_log = logging.getLogger('app_info_log')
info_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    LOG_FILENAME,
    maxBytes=1024 * 1024 * 100,
    backupCount=20
    )

info_log.addHandler(handler)

...

@app.before_request
def pre_request_logging():
    #Logging statement
    if 'text/html' in request.headers['Accept']:
        info_log.info('\t'.join([
            datetime.datetime.today().ctime(),
            request.remote_addr,
            request.method,
            request.url,
            request.data,
            ', '.join([': '.join(x) for x in request.headers])])
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably what you want is described as following.

```
LOG_FILENAME = 'app_access_logs.log'

app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) # use the native logger of flask

handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    LOG_FILENAME,
    maxBytes=1024 * 1024 * 100,
    backupCount=20
    )

app.logger.addHandler(handler)

...

@app.before_request
def pre_request_logging():
    #Logging statement
    if 'text/html' in request.headers['Accept']:
        app.logger.info('\t'.join([
            datetime.datetime.today().ctime(),
            request.remote_addr,
            request.method,
            request.url,
            request.data,
            ', '.join([': '.join(x) for x in request.headers])])
        )
```

Comment: What should be the permission / owner settings for the log file? I've been trying to get this working with my uwsgi but will only work when it is for 777 permission.

Comment: The uwsgi worker should have write permission for the log file, or you can set the log file owner/group as uwsgi worker with proper permissions.